# Remove files from Pull Request but not from git

Tags: git, pull-request

There was a branch with some committed files I needed and with some I didn't.

I branched out from it, made my changes, submitted a Pull Request.

Is there a way to remove that unneeded files from the PR, **but** in the way so when I merge, that files won't be deleted from `master` or `initial branch`?

Comment: Could you elaborate more? I don't understand. Maybe some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pull request is simply a notification or alert to teammates that you have pushed up commit(s) to the remote repo.  It provides a more formal mechanism for teammates to discuss and review code that has been pushed to the repo with the end goal being a merge.

In your case I recommend checking out a previous commit, and stashing (`git stash`) the files that you don't want to include in your commit.  Then re-commit, push to repo, and re-generate the pull request.

*Disclaimer, this isn't a recommended workflow since a pull request often ends in a merge.  If you take my approach, you would have stashed files in your local repo that may be needed before you would want to merge your initial branch into the master.